# Android MediaPlayer run with overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

thanks for reading this post, I have a problem with one of the app features that I developed, which is MediaPlayer which I run through the raw folder. The problem arises when I try to **play 2 MediaPlayer** simultaneously at the same time, another MediaPlayer should **stop automatically** when the other MediaPlayer runs, but this does not, even when exiting the activity, MediaPlayer is still running, is there a solution related to this. this is my code

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1,mediaPlayer2,mediaPlayer3;
    ImageButton btn1, btn2, btn3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hukum_ra_tarqiq);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.madtarqiqc1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.madtarqiqc2);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        mediaPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.madtarqiqc3);

    }
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq1:
                setmpFirst();
                break;
            case R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq2:
                setmpSecond();
                break;
            case R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq3:
                setmpThird();
                break;
        }
    }
private void setmpFirst(){
        if (mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()){
            if (mediaPlayer1 != null){
                mediaPlayer1.pause();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    mediaPlayer1.stop();
                    mediaPlayer1.release();
                }
            }
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        }else {
            mediaPlayer1.start();
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        }
    }

    private void setmpSecond(){
        if (mediaPlayer2.isPlaying()){
            if (mediaPlayer2 != null){
                mediaPlayer2.pause();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    mediaPlayer2.stop();
                    mediaPlayer2.release();
                }
            }
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        }
        else {
            mediaPlayer2.start();
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        }
    }

    private void setmpThird(){
        if (mediaPlayer3.isPlaying()){
            if (mediaPlayer3 != null){
                mediaPlayer3.pause();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    mediaPlayer3.stop();
                    mediaPlayer3.release();
                }
            }
            btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        }
        else {
            mediaPlayer3.start();
            btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        }
    }
```

What I want is, when MediaPlayer above is run **simultaneously**, MediaPlayer is first clicked to run, and the **others stop**, as well as when I exit the activity, MediaPlayer automatically stops, is there a solution or from the code above is there a simplification?

Comment: make MediaPlayer only one.

Comment: How? Do you have references regarding this?

Comment: I add answer. check this and i hope you happy coding.

Comment: I have followed your code, but why can't I play mp3 files from raw? and the button when clicked doesn't change

Comment: add `mediaPlayer.prepare();` before `start();`. and in my code, there is change code. So change after finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your play List. using array.

```
int[] playList = new int[3];
playList[0] = R.raw.madtarqiqc1;
playList[1] = R.raw.madtarqiqc2;
playList[2] = R.raw.madtarqiqc3;
```

and set play position in `Global Variable`

```
int play = 0;
```

and you can controll using `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener()`

for example,

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, playList[play]);
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            play++;
            if (play < playList.length) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(BackGroundSound.this, playList[play]);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } else {
                play = 0;
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(BackGroundSound.this, playList[play]);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    };
```

and when you make next button (or click event). just

```
mediaPlayer.stop(); 
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, playList[position]);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

p.s] i modify your code. check this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    ImageButton btn1, btn2, btn3;
    int[] playList;
    int play = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq1);
        btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq2);
        btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq3);

        int[] playList = new int[3];
        playList[0] = R.raw.madtarqiqc1;
        playList[1] = R.raw.madtarqiqc2;
        playList[2] = R.raw.madtarqiqc3;

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, playList[play]);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

    }

    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            play++;
            if (play < playList.length) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, playList[play]);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } else {
                play = 0;
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, playList[play]);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq1:
                playMusic(0);
                break;
            case R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq2:
                playMusic(1);
                break;
            case R.id.play_toggle_ratarqiq3:
                playMusic(2);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void playMusic(int position) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, playList[position]);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        changeView(position);
    }

    private void changeView(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
        }
    }

}
```